# When $x(t)$ and the output $y(t)$ are related by linear differential equations, why is the system unstable when $M>N$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This is two linear differential systems equating each other.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^Ny(t)}{dt^N}+a_1\frac{d^{N-1}y(t)}{dt^{N-1}}+\cdots+a_{N-1}\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+a_Ny(t)=
b_{N-M}\frac{d^Mx(t)}{dt^M}+b_{N-M+1}\frac{d^{M-1}x(t)}{dt^{M-1}}+\cdots+b_{N-1}\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+b_Nx(t)
\end{equation}

In the textbook, it states that "theoretically the powers $M$ and $N$ in the foregoing equations can take on any value. However, practical considerations make $M>N$ undesirable for two reasons." One of the reasons being, the equation acts as "$(M − N)$th-order differentiator" - to which I am confused why.

The textbook further explains that "A differentiator
represents an unstable system because a bounded input like the step input results in an unbounded
output, $\delta(t)$".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have formatted your image (and some of your text) in LaTeX (MathJax). Please double-check that I didn't mess any of the equations up. Keep practicing; writing in LaTeX gets easy with time and practice.

Comment: Thank you! will do that.